# Referencing single element in Pair object array of 2D arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

How can I  reference an array element in an array of 2D arrays structured in pairs? Thanks.

```
object [] [,] Pairs = new object [3] [,];
Pairs[0]= new object [,] {{Array1 , Array2}};
Pairs[1]= new object [,] {{Array3, Array4}};
Pairs[2]= new object [,] {{Array5, Array6 }};


foreach (var o in Pairs)
{

    SelectedArray = [???] //Trying to select Array1 here
```

Comment: Selman has your answer below, but you might want to think about whether there is a better data structure to meet your need than an array of 2D arrays because that looks kind of ugly.

Comment: I recommend you to use `Tuple<object,object,object>` or your own class instead of `object[3]`. But anyway it really looks ugly and strange

Comment: Sorry for the ugliness I am still fresh at C#, I switched recently after many years in VB

Answer (score 1):

The type of `o` is `two-dimensional` array so you can access it's values just like you can access an element of a multidimensional array:

```
foreach (var o in Pairs)
{
   SelectedArray = o[0,0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Selman, i tried that and it gives me this error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'object[*,*]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @danodan what is the type of SelectedArray ?

Comment: the type for selectedArray is object[,]

Comment: @danodan then why are you trying to assigh it an array? types are not compatible one of them is object and other one is object[,] there is no way to assign one to another. maybe you should reconsider what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: because I am passing it a 2D array to use inside the foreach